# To which wireless access point is my Chromebook connected?

Tags: home-networking, chromebook, google-chrome-os

In my house I have three wireless access points (192.168.88.247, 192.168.88.253, 192.168.88.254) all connected to the same router/modem (192.168.88.1). For convenience, all three access points share the same ssid and password.

How can I find out the IP address of the access point to which my Chromebook is connected?

I looked under Network in Chrome OS settings. It tells me the Chromebook's IP address in the local network (192.168.88.243), and the the address of the router, but I can't see the address of the access point. How can I find this out from within Chrome OS? Surely it knows?

[image]

Comment: It will connect to the one with the strongest signal.

Comment: bssid. check your ap's setting to find the matching one.

Comment: "It will connect to the one with the strongest signal." So I hoped, but weirdly my Pixelbook was connecting to a distant access point on 2.4 GHz over a much closer 5 GHz-only access point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection to your WiFi access point is, simplified, a connection from MAC-ID to MAC-ID. In this case, the MAC-ID of the access point is found under `bssid`.

To know the IP address of the access point that you connect to must match that MAC-ID with the router's IP address. You should probably look on the router's status page, where you might find something like:

```
Wireless
    Wireless Radio: Enabled
    Name (SSID):    nogeentje
    Channel:        13
    Mode:           54Mbps (802.11g)
    MAC Address:    00-16-0A-14-49-2A
    IP Address:     192.168.178.254
```

(this is an example of one of my routers). If you have a table MAC<->IP address, you can use that to look-up the IP address.

Note: ChromeOS doesn't seem to have a simple `arp -a`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Interestingly, each access point has different but adjacent MAC address for ethernet and wireless.